# How do I keep an element from pushing another element in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am new to positioning in CSS, and am trying to learn... This is my first question on here, too. =)

Here's what I've got going on.

Below is the screenshot:

[image]

See how the red triangle is pushing the picture down in my page header, creating that dark strip of color? I'd like instead for the red triangle (`.flag`) to overlay on top of the picture, like it's hanging over it like a ribbon.

I'm not sure all what code you'd need to see for this but here's the triangle (`.flag`)'s CSS:

```
.flag {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid transparent;
    border-top: 60px solid $red;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="new visible-l">
        <a href="#">
            <h3>NEW?</h3>
            <p>Click here to learn more!</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">The Quigley Inn</a></h1>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Logs</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Bulletin</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Locations</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Directory</a> |</li>
        <li><a href="#">Policies</a> </li>
        <li class="hidden-l">| <a href="#" class="newhidden">New?</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="flag visible-l"></div>

</section>

<section id="content">
<section id="pageheader">

    <img src="http://placekitten.com/1200/400" />

    <h1>The Quigley Inn</h1>

</section>
```

Comment: I could not browse to the picture.

Comment: Is this a live website? Could you provide the URL?

Comment: Bah, I don't know why the tinypic isn't working. Here it is on imgur. And no it's not live, yet. http://imgur.com/dcBpsNX

Comment: Not sure if this would be wanted, but it is on https://github.com/StacyKendra/Quigley

Comment: @StacyK.Basye Can you post your HTML code of the area which holds the image of the cat?

Comment: @FahadHasan I have done so. It's the placekitten image.

Comment: I've posted a solution below, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to absolutely position the `.flag` element and then position it using the `top` and the `right` properties, like this:

```
.flag {
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-left: 80px solid transparent;
     border-right: 80px solid transparent;
     border-top: 60px solid red;
     position: absolute;
     right: 40px;
     top: //insert appropriate value
}
```

Another workaround of this would be to simply move your cat image/div up using `margin-top` with a negative value, for e.g. `margin-top: -10px`.

**UPDATE:**

Please add the CSS below to your stylesheet:

```
section#pageheader img {
     margin-top: -50px;
}

.flag {
     z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: All right the margin-top totally fixed the position of the image... But for some reason, z-index: 9999 is doing absolutely nothing. So the bottom of the triangle gets cut off by the image.

Comment: Oh! I just tried adding `position: relative` to it along with the z-index and it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Without much code given, my first guess would be to apply `position: relative; bottom: 50px;` (assuming the picture is being pushed down 50px, you should change as needed) to whatever element is containing the picture/all that stuff. Then, put a `z-index: 100` on the on the ribbon so it's on top of the picture.

Comment: Thanks. =) Unfortunately, I tried what you suggested just now, and it didn't quite work. I put the `position: relative; bottom: 50px;` on the image itself (because putting it in the image's container didn't make the bar go away. I probably could have fixed that by decreasing the top margin on the neon-looking header beneath there, but the ribbon doesn't pop on top of everythng with `z-index: 100` regardless.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above solutions worked, try this.

add `position: absolute;` and `right: 0px;` to the ribbon container

then add `position: relative` to the parent div that center aligns all content in the header bar.

Comment: Putting `position: absolute;` on the ribbon's triangle works GREAT for fixing the problem with the header... the only problem is that it doesn't align under the rest of the ribbon (the box with the text) because when I expand or shrink the window, the triangle moves with it. My whole site's responsive.

Comment: Added it to the main question.